# Where was the Japanese surrender signed on Okinawa in June 1945?

Tags: world-war-two, geography

On the 21st of June, Japanese defences on the southern fringe of Okinawa collapsed. The following day General Mitsuru Ushijima and chief of staff Isamu Chō committed suicide. Colonel Yahara was denied permission to commit suicide and presumably negotiated surrender terms with allied forces:

> If you die there will be no one left who knows the truth about the
>   battle of Okinawa. Bear the temporary shame but endure it. This is an
>   order from your army Commander.

Where and when (latitude and longitude if possible) was the surrender signed?

Comment: I have one also but I'm sure mine is a copy.

Comment: my dad was the secretary for general buckner. when he died he was the sec for stilwell. I just found a document of surrender it matches the same as bill jamieson's description. if you are reading this bill , please email me at besthomes21@gmail.com. I can scan and send you my copy to compare against yours.
I believe they must have signed several copies.

Comment: I too have a copy of the surrender doc. (There were 10 original signed). My father was there working for vinegar Joe. With the doc I have the pics and a hand typed account of that day. I have tried to find this doc on line but can't

Comment: Can you post a photo?

Comment: I wonder what what meant by "temporary shame".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Japanese surrendered formally on Okinawa on September 7th, 1945 at the [Tenth Army Headquarters.](http://www.history.navy.mil/photos/events/wwii-pac/japansur/js-10o.htm) There is relatively little concrete detail about exactly where the 10th Army was headquartered at the time but given that their [initial landing](http://www.history.army.mil/books/wwii/okinawa/map-5.htm) was near Yomitan and their [current headquarters](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/facility/torii-station.htm) is in the [vicinity](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Yomitan,+Okinawa,+Japan&aq=0&sll=26.472447,127.918879&sspn=1.116185,2.705383&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Yomitan,+Nakagami+District,+Okinawa+Prefecture,+Japan&ll=26.379337,127.746277&spn=0.036755,0.084543&t=m&z=14), I'd expect them to be one in the same. The GPS coordinates since you asked are roughly [N26° 22' 47" by E127° 44' 05".](http://boulter.com/gps/?c=26.38%20127.74#26.38%20127.735)

Comment: Thanks @world-engineer that may be the best answer I am like to get. Unless Colonel Yahara included the details in his book. I will hold out for that for a while ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I clarified my false assumption about Yahara by grabbing a copy of his book (see my update). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great. Many people think soldiers had **surrendered** before Aug 15, 1945, when the then cabinet officially accepted the Postdam Announcement. But actually, even most of the island was occupied by American soldiers, in many island the soldiers did not **officially** surrendered until, at least on Aug 15 1945 ( the first **entire** surrender by Japan )

Answer (score 3):

I have had what I thought was the original surrender document. I know there will be doubt on this one, but bought it at a rummage sale, and it was in an old picture frame. It is signed by 4 individuals, including Gen. Stillwell. I am convinced it is the original, and I know there will be doubters out there, but what can I say.

It does have boundaries on it, but some numbers are faded. The numbers are:
30 North 126 East, thence 24 North 122 East, thence 24 North 133 East, thence 29 North 131 East, thence, (faded writing) 131 30 East, thence to point of origin.

The signatures on it are raised, and has X on top of the document.

It is signed by JW Stilwell (Vinegar Joe).

I am too lazy to put down the Japanese names, but they are or look very authentic.

It is basically all calligraphy.

It is dated 7 September 1945.

Comment: Please don't invite discussion in an answer - please limit answers to just the material that answers a question.

Comment: That is pretty interesting. Could you post a photo or scan?

Answer (score 2):

So my assumptions about Yahara signing the surrender terms soon after the collapse were unsound. Reading the interrogation report included as an appendix of his [book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Okinawa_kessen.html?id=uqbLPwAACAAJ) it is clear that instead Yahara managed to evade capture for several days before being picked up by local CIC agents. He remained a prisoner until January 1946 when he was repatriated to Japan and was not involved in surrender ceremonies on the 7th of September.

Comment: Moved my update into an answer (/cc @MarkC.Wallace)